# Is there any way to send a DM to Slash Command author in nextcord/discord.py?

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

Ive tried the following code:

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def test(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.author.send_message(f"Test DM")
```

But it gives me the following error: `nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'InteractionResponse' object has no attribute 'author'`

I have no idea on how to fix this, ive tried searching and I can't find anything, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the docs would tell you that [`InteractionResponse.author`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.InteractionResponse) indeed doesn't exist. Using random attributes/methods and hoping it leads somewhere rarely does anything useful.

Similarly, another quick look at the docs will tell you that [`Interaction`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Interaction) has a [`user`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Interaction.user) attribute of which the description is

> The user or member that sent the interaction.

Comment: Ty! I took a reference at the `ctx.author` so I got a little confused.

Comment: Even then, `Interaction` is the equivalent of `Context`, not `Interaction.response`, so that would be the place to look. Either way, if it solved your problem you should accept my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to DM the command author, but it just gives me another error. I've tried using `interaction.user.send_message` and `interaction.response.user.send_message` and neither of them worked. Im going to look at the docs hoping i will find something.

Comment: Looking at the docs i found `interaction.user.create_dm`, which lets me create a DM and then by using `interaction.user.dm_channel.send` it lets me send a direct message to the user. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also just do `user.send` as a shortcut. And once again, if it solved your problem you should accept my answer.